# No Truffle : Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js

before marking this question as a duplicate please notice that I'm not using truffle :)

So the problem is , everytime I send a transaction to my smart contract I get the error from title.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const EthUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');
const wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const testNetWS = "ws://...:";
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(testNetWS));
const parameters = require('./parameters.js');
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(parameters.getSCABI(), parameters.getSCAddress());
const nonceCounterMap = new Map();
const account = "0x9cc01300194131b04cf297d9a0ebbef0ae011241";
const privateKey = "0x...";



router.get('/sendTheSmartContract', async function(req,res,next){

  // nonce
  var nonce = await getNewMaxNonce(account);
  const nonceHex = web3.utils.toHex(nonce);

  // gasLimit
  const gasLimit = "0x59a5380"; //"0xE0000000"; // from genesis

  // Gas price
  var gasPriceInWei;
    await web3.eth.getGasPrice()
    .then(  function(value){
                gasPriceInWei = value;
            }
    );

  var gasPriceInWeiHex = web3.utils.toHex(gasPriceInWei);

  // Tw-x
  var dataTx = myContract.methods.saveString('Test').encodeABI();

  var rawTx = {
    "nonce": nonceHex,
    "gasPrice": 0,
    "gasLimit": gasLimit,
    "to": parameters.getSCAddress(),
    "data": dataTx,
    "value": '0x01',
    "chainId": 71242
  }

  var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
  tx.sign( EthUtil.toBuffer(privateKey) );

  var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
  .on('transactionHash', async function(hash){ console.log("Transaction hash step , DONE : " + hash); })
  .on('confirmation', async function(conf){ console.log("Confirmation step , DONE : " + JSON.stringify(conf)); })
  .on('receipt', async function(result){ console.log("Receipt step , DONE : " + JSON.stringify(result)); })
  .on('error', async function(err){ console.log("Sending signed transaction operation , STATUS : FAILED !!");console.error(err); });

});

});
```

I'm using NodeJS & ExpressJS.
There's a list with the versions of my imports from the code snippet above :

```
    "ethereumjs-tx": "^1.3.7",
    "ethereumjs-util": "^6.1.0",
    "ethereumjs-wallet": "^0.6.3",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
```

- one & very important thing : I'm working on a quorum private blockchain.

If I set :

```
"gasPrice": gasPriceInWeiHex
```

I would get another error :

```
{"code":-32000,"message":"Gas price not 0"}
```

When I send this transaction , anyway , it's recorded on quorum blockchain dashboard and I can see the transaction , but somehow , after the "transactionHash" event ( e.g : `.on('transactionHash',` ) I get :

```
Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits
```

I think it's from the rawTx object , but I don't know what I'm missing...
I've found that Quorum is calculating the block Timestamp was in nanoseconds , but I don't know how can I check if that's the cause or if that might cause it.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was not the code but the web3 version , after I've updated to web3 2.0.0 Alpha 1

```
sudo npm install web3@2.0.0-alpha.1
```

everything worked.

PS : Old web3 version was : web3 1.0.0 beta 52

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommend to use 3.x

So I resolve this by upgrading to 3.x.

`npm i web3@3.0.0-rc.5`